# Lazy Loading with ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a directive that is simply a collapsible/expandable section on a page that transcludes any content that is given to it. Currently I have a page that has several of these expandable sections that contains a bunch of survey-like questions. One problem I seem to be having is that the page loads unbearably slow for any browser other than chrome. Is it possible to make the transclude have a lazy-loading functionality? Would it be possible for example, if all the sections loaded collapsed and then when clicked on, they would compile/load the transcluded content then expand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the preferred way of lazy loading data for an ng-include in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962931/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-lazy-loading-data-for-an-ng-include-in-angular)

Comment: Not quite, I am already capable of hiding/showing the contents, but I need to be able to control the compilation time of the transcluded stuff.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to be a way of unflagging that, my bad!

Comment: Question is still actuall. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can directives be lazy loaded in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538665/how-can-directives-be-lazy-loaded-in-angularjs)